# why abstract class allow protected method and why not in interface?

Tags: java

I read some questions answer but still not clear

**why abstract class allow protected method and why not in interface?**

Interface: to access method for common so only avoid protected.
Then why abstract method allow protected method?

Comment: Study abstract class vs interface and know use of interface and abstract class

Comment: Studied. All are explained rules and regulation and difference only.
Nobody explain about Why follow that rules ?

Comment: read https://dzone.com/articles/when-to-use-abstract-class-and-intreface

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan
why Protected in abstract?

Abstract : You want to share code among several closely related classes.

Interfaces: form a contract between the class and the outside world not only subclass

Is it correct or not?

Comment: yap, you are right